# XML Shredding to include attribute and inner element value

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, shred

Consider the following XML fragment:

```
<Orders>
  <Totals>
     <Total Type="Merchandise">56.89</Total>
     <Total Type="Shipping">10.75</Total>
     <Total Type="Tax">0.00</Total>
     <Total Type="Order">67.64</Total>
     <Total Type="Discount">0.00</Total>
     <Total Type="ServiceFee">0.00</Total>
     <Total Type="ServiceFeeDiscount">0.00</Total>
  </Totals>  
</Orders>
```

I'd like to (using SQL's built in XQuery/XPath support), shred the Type attribute and the value of each Total into its own column and the inner value of each element into its own column, as seen below:

```
    Type           Amount  
Merchandise        56.89  
  Shipping         10.75  
     Tax            0.00
```

I've used all of the XQuery and XPath I know, to no avail.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, don't know why I couldn't figure this out before.  See code below:

```
select T.data.value('@Type', 'varchar(20)'),
   T.data.value('.', 'varchar(20)')
from @data.nodes('Orders/Totals/Total') T(data)
```